# Search for duplicates, if found sum values

Tags: php, php-7

I have this array :

```
$data = [
    0 => [
       'date'       => '2018-09-12',
       'department' => 12,
       'country'    => 14,
       'total'      => 12
    ],
    1 => [
       'date'       => '2018-09-12',
       'department' => 12,
       'country'    => 14,
       'total'      => 18
    ],
    2 => [
       'date'       => '2018-09-12',
       'department' => 12,
       'country'    => 15,
       'total'      => 10
    ]
];
```

The return should be :

```
$return = [
   0 => [
       'date'       => '2018-09-12',
       'department' => 12,
       'country'    => 14,
       'total'      => 30
   ],
   1 => [
       'date'       => '2018-09-12',
       'department' => 12,
       'country'    => 15,
       'total'      => 10
   ]
];
```

I tried like this :

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
     if(!in_array($value, $data)) {
         $result[] = $data;
     }
}
```

The idea is, if all fields except total are indentical, then add total to the existing total with the same fields. Please help me. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: You will need to walk through each array item and compare the date, department, and country to see if they are the same and then add the totals.  Then put that info into a new array item and remove the 2 old ones.  Maybe there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by looping through your array, comparing all the other values of each element (`date`, `department` and `country`) with previously seen values and summing the totals when you get a match. This code uses [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to generate a composite key of the other values for comparison:

```
$output = array();
$keys = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $total = $value['total'];
    unset($value['total']);
    $key = serialize($value);
    if (($k = array_search($key, $keys)) !== false) {
        $output[$k]['total'] += $total;
    }
    else {
        $keys[] = $key;
        $output[] = array_merge($value, array('total' => $total));
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [date] => 2018-09-12
        [department] => 12
        [country] => 14
        [total] => 30 
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [date] => 2018-09-12
        [department] => 12
        [country] => 15
        [total] => 10
     ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Bngio)

By using the composite key as the index into the `$output` array, we can simplify this code, we just need to use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) after the loop to re-index the `$output` array:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $v = $value;
    unset($v['total']);
    $key = serialize($v);
    if (isset($output[$key])) {
        $output[$key]['total'] += $value['total'];
    }
    else {
        $output[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$output = array_values($output);
print_r($output);
```

Output is the same as before. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WfKBp)

Comment: Nice answer!  What does this line do?  `$output[] = array_merge($value, array('total' => $total));`

Comment: @dmikester1 because I took the `total` value out of the `$value` array so that I could generate the composite key from it, I have to put it back into the value being stored into the `$output` array so there is a total when we see the first occurrence of a composite key.

Comment: The unset and serialize is a cleaver way to ensure uniqueness in this situation! Great answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this method as it doesn't involve much memory intensive operations such as merging, especially while working with large amount of data:

```
$new_data=[];
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $i=array_search($value["date"],array_column($new_data,"date"));
    if(($i!==false)&&($new_data[$i]["department"]==$value["department"])&&($new_data[$i]["country"]==$value["country"])){
        $new_data[$i]["total"]+=$value["total"];
    }
    else{
        $new_data[]=$value;
    }
}
print_r($new_data);
```